# Hook::exec is not working for a particular module

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I am facing an issue regarding the hook::exec in my prestashop application, where module and hook method is installed properly. But when I tried to execute this module, it return false. Kindly suggest me. Module and hook method is showing in "**Modules and Services / Positions**" as well as `ps_hook` table in database.

Module base file is defined as :

```php
public function __construct()
{
  $this->name = 'callback';
  $this->tab = 'front_office_features';
  $this->version = '1.0';

  $this->author = 'Amit Jha';
  $this->need_instance = 0;
  $this->ps_versions_compliancy = array('min' => '1.6', 'max' => _PS_VERSION_);

  $this->bootstrap = true;

  parent::__construct();

    $this->displayName = $this->l( 'Call Back' );
    $this->description = $this->l( '....' );
    $this->confirmUninstall = $this->l( 'Are you sure you want to uninstall? .... ' );
}
```

And Install method is as below:

```php
if ( parent::install() && $this->registerHook( 'displayCallBack' ) && $this->registerHook( 'displayHeader' ) && $this->registerHook( 'displayCallBackCart' ) && $this->registerHook( 'displayCallBackLinkOnCartPopup' ) && $this->registerHook( 'displayCallBackLinkOnCartPopupWishlist' ) ) {
    if ( !$this->alterTable( 'add' ) ) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Hook Method:

```php
public function hookDisplayCallBack( $params )
{
    $results = CallBackServiceCore::searchDetail();

    if ( count( $results ) <= 0 ) {
        return;
    }
    foreach ( $results as $item ) {
        $this->context->smarty->assign( array(
            'description_text' => $item["description_text"],
            'recall_promise' => $item["recall_promise"]
        ) );
    }

    $arrDate = $this->getCallingTime();

    $this->context->smarty->assign( array(
        'arrTimeList' => $arrDate,
        'product_id' => $params["product"]->id,
        'product_name' => $params["product"]->name,
        'category' => $params["product"]->category
      )
    );

    return $this->display( __file__, 'display.tpl' );
}
```

Please suggest where I made mistake.

Comment: "But when I tried to execute this module, it return false" Could you elaborate a bit more? What code is returning false? Can you show your hook methods?

Comment: I write a code for test only purpose in frontController : if ( Hook::exec( 'displayCallBack', array('product' => $this->product) ) ) {
            exit( "executed" );
        } 
        exit( "Not executed" );

Comment: It works on Single store. I think there is problem with Prestashop, in case of multi-store it creates problem with module functionalities.